# Get music BPM/tempo

Tags: java, android, business-process-management, tempo

We are adding a function to our Android app, in which we would like to get the music tempo/BPM (either playing in our own app, or in another app), and then visualize the song or music with FFT or similar stuff. 
Something synchronizes like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVrf89SXvTM

Can anyone nice to teach us how can I get the music tempo? Or any tutorials?
I appreciate any provided answer.

Comment: your question is too broad, check this related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339706/get-bpm-of-song-in-android

Comment: Thanks, @JoaquinAlvarez! So is it doable to detect sound energy by locating its peaks, other than recording the sound? In that case, is it the mike that is used for sound detection?